# Read headers of response in MassTransit Response-Request

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MassTransit v.5* with Rabbit MQ and I am doing a normal Request-Response as in http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html .

I am setting a header on the response message in consumer like

```
await context.RespondAsync<OrderStatusResult>(
        new 
        {
            OrderId = order.Id,
            Timestamp = order.Timestamp,
            StatusCode = order.StatusCode,
            StatusText = order.StatusText
        }
    , callback => callback.Headers.Set("key", "value"))
```

I see this headers as being set by looking in RabbitMQ, but on the caller's end there is no way I can access these header.

So, how can I access the headers for Response message on caller's end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new request client, instead of the original one, and you can access the message context with the response.

```
var client = Bus.CreateRequestClient<GetOrderStatus>(ServiceAddress);

var request = new GetOrderStatus(...);
var response = await client.GetResponse<OrderStatusResult>(request);
// response is type Response<OrderStatusResult>

var headerValue = response.Headers.Get...("key")
```

Comment: With the old, I could do something like `var client = _busControl.CreateRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(
                exchangeAddress,
                timeout,
                timeToLive,
                context =>
                {
                    context.Durable = false;
                    context.Headers // add header here!
                });` which is pretty valuable to me. But with the new one, all I can set is the timeout. So time to live and access to SendContext are no longer available. Is this intentional?

Comment: You can set anything on the context if you use client.Create(request) and use the RequestHandle to set those things, then call GetResponse on the request handle. Also, you can specify a default TTL when you create the request client so you don't have to specify it each call.

Comment: You can see how in the unit tests for the client: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Futures.Tests/Request_Specs.cs#L49

Comment: This is exactly what I would need. ```using (var requestHandle = client.Create(request))   { ...} ``` is working well the first time I call it, but always on the second call I get a nasty "[InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]"  Things to mention, my method this is called in is not async-await as I am working in an legacy project.Still have to dig into it, maybe I can do a proper jon on it. Thank you for all help, it's been great and eye-opening. Any extra tip would be a nice bonus.

Comment: The code:``` private TResponse RpcCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan timeToLive)
            where TRequest : class where TResponse : class
        {
            var exchangeAddress = GetDestinationExchangeAddress<TRequest>();
            var client = _busControl.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(exchangeAddress, timeout);

            TResponse response = Activator.CreateInstance<TResponse>();

            using (var requestHandle = client.Create(request))
            {
               
            }

            return response;
        }```

Comment: So in my case just creating the handle will make the call fail with the above error.

Comment: I converted it to async-await to same results. Also, the app is hosted in IIS.

Comment: if you post a complete code example of what is failing, that would help. Comments are impossible to read code.